# Javascript - Object Value not Updating after Moving between Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am moving one object from one holders array to another:

```
for (var x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
    var i = holder1.array.length - 1;
    while (i >= 0) {
        var object = array[holder1.array[i].index];
        holder1.array[i].splice(i, 1);
        object.owner = i;
        object.index = x;
        holder2.array.push(object);
        i--;
    }
}
```

I then change the data like so:

```
for (var i = 0; i < holders.length; i++) {
    var holderActive = holders[i];
    if (holderActive.array.length > 0) {
        for (var x = 0; x < holderActive.array.length; x++) {
            var object = array[holderActive.array[x].index];
            console.log(object.property); << ALWAYS THE SAME!
            object.property ++;
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am editing the property of the object, but every time this is run, the property is logged as the same value. What is going on here?

Comment: In each iteration you have new object. If initial `property` value for every object is the same, than it will always display same value.

Comment: Why do I have a new object? Arent I creating a reference by saying:
var object = array[holder1.array[i].index];

Comment: `var holderActive = holders[i];` is not `holder2` from the code you posted. I think you need to provide more information.